# Using a Font Awesome Icon with react-select v2?

Tags: reactjs, font-awesome, react-select

Using: https://react-select.com/home I've been trying variations of the following idea:

```
 const hex = 'f2bc';
 const char = unescape('%u' + hex);
 <Select
   defaultValue={ label: char, value: 'some-value'}
   ...={...}/>
```

This is the result of the above attempt:

[image]

Comment: what did you tried, what was your expected result, what results did you have?

Comment: How did you include Font Awesome?

Comment: Also, [f2bc doesn't seem to exist](https://fontawesome.com/cheatsheet). Which icon is it supposed to be?

Comment: @JJJ you're right, that icon doesn't exist.  Any icon would do, I must've mistyped it.  Also I was trying to just use the unicode and get away with not including Font Awesome, but I don't think that is possible.
I got the idea because running this in the chrome console will return the TM icon:
let unicode = '2122';
let convertedUnicode = unescape('%u' + unicode);
console.log(convertedUnicode)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`react-select` is flexible to allow `PropTypes.node` to be passed for the [`label` option](https://github.com/JedWatson/react-select/blob/v2.0.0/src/builtins.js#L7).

`font-awesome` icons [can be used with className](https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/on-the-web/referencing-icons/basic-use) applied to an HTMLSpan element e.g.

```
const labelWithIcon = <span className="fas fa-stroopwafel" />

<Select defaultValue={{ label: labelWithIcon, value: 'some-value' }} />
```

Comment: In this configuration the tooltip displays '[object object]'

Comment: It appears to me that you're using a different library together with `react-select`. I don't think that is addressable as part of the original question.

Answer (score 4):

To dispaly icons instead of text you can do like this :

```
const options = [
      { value: "text", label: <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faFileAlt} /> },
      { value: "image", label: <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faFileImage} /> },
      { value: "video", label: <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faFileVideo} /> }
];

<Select  placeholder="Text"  options={options} />
```